# Creating users with or without schemas?

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, relational-database

Let's say I want to create simple database, for a simple book store application. I think i should have minimum two users: admin, which has privileges to create, modify and drop objects and user, having just select and insert privileges.

I am a little confused here. Should I create a user account with normal schema or with empty schema? Should the user has privileges to select and query from admin schema which contains tables or it is a user schema that should contain these tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different ways to approach this sort of problem.  So a great deal depends on your application architecture.

You would generally create one database account that owns the database objects-- tables, packages, views, etc. Let's call this account `BOOKSTORE_OWNER`.  This account would generally be locked so that no one could log in as `BOOKSTORE_OWNER` other during periodic builds.

Beyond that starting point, however, there are a host of reasonable ways to deal with authentication and authorization.  If you wanted to let the database handle both, you would create two roles-- `BOOKSTORE_USER` and `BOOKSTORE_ADMIN`.  Those roles would be given appropriate privileges on the objects owned by `BOOKSTORE_OWNER`.  You would then create a database user for every person that can use the application and grant the appropriate role to each new user.  So if you're an admin and I'm a user, the database account `dygi` would be created and granted the `BOOKSTORE_ADMIN` role while the database account `Justin` would be created and granted the `BOOKSTORE_USER` role.

This approach worked quite well when people were building client-server applications.  If you are using a three-tier application, on the other hand, you want the middle tier connection pool to use the same credentials to connect to the database rather than having each user have their own database connections.  The simplest way to accomplish this is to create a single `BOOKSTORE_APP` database account, grant that account all the privileges of the `BOOKSTORE_ADMIN` and `BOOKSTORE_USER` role, and then let the application implement the logic to figure out which front end user has what privileges.  This would generally entail a `USER`, `PRIVILEGE`, and `USER_PRIVILEGE` table in the `BOOKSTORE_OWNER` schema.  This approach can work quite well.  The downside, though, is that every application has to build its own logic for managing privileges which can get quite complex over time.  It also can make it somewhat difficult to report on what privileges users have or to ensure that a user's privileges are kept up to date when users leave the organization or move to a new role.

Oracle in particular addresses many of these challenges by allowing [proxy authentication](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adgsec03.htm).  This allows you to mix the benefits of the client-server approach where every user has their own database account that leverages Oracle's existing privilege management infrastructure with the connection pooling benefits of using a shared database account.  This works very well but only works with Oracle and then only with certain protocols (OCI and JDBC) so it is not terribly popular.

Of course, beyond these basics, you can get into quite a bit of complexity.  You may want to have [enterprise users](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/network.920/a96573/asomeus.htm#1004604) where Oracle doesn't maintain the password but instead allows the user to authenticate against an external LDAP directory.  You may want to manage privileges with LDAP roles rather than with rows in application-specific tables.  You may want to integrate with various middle-tier single sign-on (SSO) solutions.

Comment: It's just a complete answer to my question. Thank You for describing details on client/server and middle-tier authentication methods. Didn't realize it affects so much the database design.